# Why do I a have Syntax error in the having clause?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, where-clause, having

I don't understand why I have a syntax error in the >. I'm trying to verify that if delivery in person=1, then the number of locationIds associated is greater than 1.

For reference, this is the assignment
" A member can only insert a book copy if he/she is a vendor. Note that for a member to be a vendor the attributes DeliveryInPerson and ExpectedResponseTime must be filled, and there must be at least one payment method associated. If DeliveryInPerson = 1, there must be at least one location associated with that member. Additionally, when the book copy is inserted, the date of insertion must be filled with the current date"

```
Create or alter trigger tr1
on Book_Copies
instead of insert
as

insert into BOOK_COPIES(VENDORID, BOOKID, AVAILABLE, BOOKUSAGE, BOOKPICTURE, INSERTIONDATE)
select i.VENDORID, i.BOOKID, i.AVAILABLE, i.BOOKUSAGE, i.BOOKPICTURE, getdate()
from inserted i, MEMBERS m, PAYMENT_METHODS_MEMBERS pm, LOCATIONS_MEMBERS lm
where m.DELIVERYINPERSON is not null and m.EXPECTEDRESPONSETIME is not null 
 and i.VENDORID=M.MEMBERID and m.MEMBERID= pm.VENDORID and lm.VENDORID=m.MEMBERID and m.DELIVERYINPERSON=1
 group by pm.VENDORID
 having count( pm.PAYMENTMETHODID)>0 and case when m.DELIVERYINPERSON=1 then count(lm.LocationID)> 0 

go
```

[image]

Comment: Please correct tags, `sql-server` OR `mysql`  (They are different!)

Comment: ```... group by pm.VENDORID having ... and case when m.DELIVERYINPERSON=1 then ...```.  `m.DELIVERYINPERSON` is not available in HAVING.

Comment: ```... and case when m.DELIVERYINPERSON=1 then count(lm.LocationID)> 0``` - `CASE` have no matched `END`.

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). And using a GROUP BY clause with no aggregates inside of an INSTEAD OF trigger has the aroma of a kludge to fix a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I think you actually want `having count(pm.PAYMENTMETHODID) > 0 and (m.DELIVERYINPERSON <> 1 or count(lm.LocationID) > 0)`. Note by the way, that `count()` counts all non-nulls values, and if you have multiple 1:Many joins, you usually need to aggregate first

Comment: There are many problems with this query. You have old style joins which has created (likely accidental) cross joins. You have a group by on only on one column with multiple columns in the select. You have a case expression missing and end. As to that this is inside an instead of trigger. Triggers are a huge red flag that something is not quite right. In more than 20 years I have used maybe a total of 5 triggers, and in retrospect all but maybe 1 or 2 could have been eliminated.